# How do you work with Zend_Form_File element?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, zend-form

I've seen a lot of way to work with uploaded file, from a pure `Zend_Form` solution, to use of `Zend_File_Transfer_Http()`.

What is a workflow when there are several (some required, some optional) files within the sames form.

Should I use Zend_File_Transfer_Http or Zend_Form? What 'checks' should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Any 'checks' on files uploaded you want to do, you can do by adding appropriate [validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file) to your file elements such as 'Size', 'Extension', 'IsImage'. To ensure that uploading of some files is compulsory you  could mark them as required through `setRequired()` method of a file form element. All these checks will be done by isValid() method of your Zend_Form so you don't need to worry about it too much.

As far as using Zend_File_Transfer_Http or Zend_Form for receiving files is concerned, I think that using Zend_File_Transfer_Http is a more 'low-level' operation then using standard methods for receiving files with Zend_Form (as shown in [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file)). So, I usually try to use these standard methods. Also zend manual [recommends](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html) using this standard way:

> When you are using Zend_Form you should use the APIs provided by Zend_Form and not Zend_File_Transfer directly. The file transfer support in Zend_Form is implemented with Zend_File_Transfer, so the information in this chapter may be useful for advanced users of Zend_Form.

So based on the above, it seems that you should consider using Zend_File_Transfer when you really do some non-standard processing of file uploads.

Hope that it makes sense.